# Unexpected Response Code 400 with Volley

Tags: java, android, rest, google-api

I'm attempting to use the google URL shortener API with Volley and I keep getting the response BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400. I'm using the POST request to shorten a url. My other POST on the same view is working as well. I've tried all different types of configurations with no luck and this works on my iOS app. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? My LogCat gives me next to nothing . Code here :

```
public void ShortenURL() {
        String endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIzaSyA32UQwEvxZNPClTsjZWzm6wO1xNGlkH-U";
        final String toShorten = mShortenEditText.getText().toString();

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, endpoint,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //messageContentEditText.setText("");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "URL Shortened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //parse response and display new URL in edittext
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println(error.networkResponse.toString());
                    }
                }) {
            //adding parameters to the request
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("longUrl", "http://wwww.espn.com/newyorkjets/joshmccown");
                //params.put("key", "AIzaSyA32UQwEvxZNPClTsjZWzm6wO1xNGlkH-U");
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders () throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                //headers.put("Accept","application/json");
                return headers;
            }

        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Logcat:

```
11-16 11:56:47.643 1446-1658/com.a2.reach1 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
11-16 11:56:48.710 1446-1658/com.a2.reach1 E/Volley: [321] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url
11-16 11:56:48.717 1446-1446/com.a2.reach1 W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
11-16 11:56:48.717 1446-1446/com.a2.reach1 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
11-16 11:56:48.717 1446-1446/com.a2.reach1 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
11-16 11:56:48.717 1446-1446/com.a2.reach1 I/System.out: com.android.volley.NetworkResponse@df41f55
11-16 11:56:48.802 1446-1503/com.a2.reach1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa12fcf60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa12f9670)
11-16 11:56:48.917 1446-1503/com.a2.reach1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa12fcf60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa12f9670)
11-16 11:57:12.221 1446-1453/com.a2.reach1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.226ms
```

This was from Hurl.it

```
Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 17 Nov 2017 04:15:06 GMT
Expires: Fri, 17 Nov 2017 04:15:06 GMT
Server: GSE
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "parseError",
"message": "Parse Error"
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Parse Error"
}
}
```

Comment: this is the response - {
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "message": "Required",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": "resource.longUrl"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Required"
    }
}


i think you should send some data along with the post method. the api might need it. read the api doc that you are using.

Comment: I'm running it in the google api console and it works with the solo parameter. I also run it in iOS and it works there with the same single parameter.

Comment: try to do it with postman. if it works then look for fault in your code. otherwise its the api. do care to post your api params and response with all details of possible.

Comment: you have added www**w** remove one **w** and just add **slash** here and let me know if it works?  `params.put("longUrl", "http://www.espn.com/newyorkjets/joshmccown/"`

Comment: nope :( doesn't work either. I added the response from hurl.it

Comment: try using getBody() instead of getParams()

Comment: getBody() WORKED! Thank you so much. put a sentence in an answer below so i can up vote you !!